# How to include scripts automatically in a yeoman/grunt project?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, yeoman, grunt-usemin

I have a working yeoman project. I am using grunt-usemin.

To include javascripts, I do this in `index.html`:

```
<!-- build:js scripts/includes.js -->
<script src="/bower_components/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/angular-ui-date/src/date.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/angulartics/src/angulartics.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/angulartics/src/angulartics-ga.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/jquery-ui/ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/vendor/bootstrap.2.3.1.min.js"></script>
... a few more libs like that

<script src="/scripts/config.processed.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/app.js"></script>

<script src="/scripts/controllers/first_controller.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/controllers/second_controller.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/controllers/third_controller.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/controllers/fourth_controller.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/controllers/fith_controller.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/controllers/sixth_controller.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/controllers/seventh_controller.js"></script>
... 20 more like that

<script src="/scripts/directives/first_directive.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/directives/second_directive.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/directives/third_directive.js"></script>
... 10 more like that

<script src="/scripts/services/first_service.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/services/second_service.js"></script>
...

<script src="/scripts/filters/first_filter.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/filters/second_filter.js"></script>
...
<!-- endbuild -->
```

This is verbose. I would like to be able to do something like this:

In `index.html`:

```
<!-- build:js scripts/includes.js -->

<!-- library includes as before -->
<script src="/bower_components/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="/bower_components/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
...

<!-- Replace application includes with this: -->
<script src="<% '/scripts/**/*.js' %>"></script>

<!-- endbuild -->
```

Answer (score 41):

I used [grunt-include-source](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-include-source)

Install it:

```
npm install grunt-include-source --save-dev
```

**In Gruntfile:**

Load it before initConfig:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
  ...
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-include-source');
```

Configure includeSource itself in initConfig:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  ...,
  includeSource: {
      options: {
        basePath: 'app',
        baseUrl: '/',
      },
      server: {
        files: {
          '.tmp/index.html': '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'
        }
      },
      dist: {
        files: {
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/index.html': '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'
        }
      }
    }
```

Add this task where you want (here, I add it to the build task):

```
grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'includeSource:dist',
    'useminPrepare',
    ...
```

Add it to the watch task:

```
watch: {
  ...,
  includeSource: {
    files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'],
    tasks: ['includeSource:server']
  }
```

Change useminPrepare (if you use yeoman)

```
useminPrepare: {
  // changed from app to dist, to take index.html processed by includeSource in dist
  html: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/index.html',
  options: {
    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
  }
},
```

I've used to subtasks: dist and server to generate the index.html in different directories.

---

**Edit**: How to include your javascripts in index.html:

```
<!-- build:js({.tmp,dist,app}) /scripts/application.js -->
<!-- vendor, external -->
<script src="/bower_components/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/vendor/underscore.extentions.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/select2/select2.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/angular-ui-select2/src/select2.js"></script>

<!-- entry point -->
<script src="/scripts/config.processed.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/app.js"></script>

<!--include everything in scripts/ except files directly inside scripts (without subdirectory) -->
<!-- include: "type": "js", "files": ["scripts/**/*.js", "!scripts/*.js"] -->

<!-- endbuild -->
```

If you want to include everything scripts, do this:

```
<!-- include: "type": "js", "files": "scripts/**/*.js" -->
```

Comment: What was your HTML index file like? I followed everything but cannot find how to make it work because I dont know the HTML comment tags, Thanks!

Comment: I'm using Yeoman with angular and ionic/cordova and for this example (which works, thanks!) you need to think of /www as the distribution folder.  For example, includeSource:dist should point to www/index.html.

Comment: Also, my grunt file has `require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);` so I didn't need to use loadNpmTasks()

Comment: Alternatively, you can just create the file in the same directory (overwrite) using `grunt serve`, and configure it to load into www on `build`

Comment: Thank you.  I cannot help but remark that this seems like it's needlessly complicated, but that's hardly your fault.

Comment: The update helped me a lot. Had just messed up the index file. Agree with @casey,`grunt-include-source`  is (or should not be) neccesary :) +1 for the good explanation.