# How do I generate a list of files in html, using a grunt task?

Tags: gruntjs

I am using yeoman, grunt and angularjs and am new to grunt.

I have some content generation that produces something like this, already copied to the dist folder.

```
/dist/whatever/x/a.html
/dist/whatever/y/b.html
/dist/whatever/x/c.html
```

I would like to create another html file using a grunt task:

```
/dist/whatever/index.html
```

Which contains:

```
...
<a href="x/a.html">x</x>
<a href="y/b.html">x</x>
<a href="x/c.html">x</x>
...
```

This html file can exist in my /app folder as a template, and have grunt replace some tokens.

Is there an existing module that does anything like this (looking for files matching a pattern and writing them into existing content)?

---

solution based on Matt's comment to use grunt-include-source:

Gruntfile.js:

```
includeSource: {
  options: {
    basePath: 'dist/whatever',
    baseUrl: '',
    templates: {
      html: {
        link: '<li><a href="{filePath}">{filePath}</a></li>'
      }
    }
  },
  whateverIndex: {
    files: {
      'dist/whatever/index.html': 'app/whatever/index.template.html'
    }
  }
},
```

app/whatever/index.template.html

```
<ul>
<!-- include: "type": "link", "files": "*/index.html" -->
</ul>
```

Comment: [grunt-include-source](https://github.com/jwvdiermen/grunt-include-source) does that sort of thing for css and js, but I don't know if it will inject anchor tags like that.  It might be a start or a good term to use for new searches.

Comment: That was perfect! You should make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`grunt-include-source` can be used to build sections in HTML that reference css, js and HTML files in a directory or that match a glob.

The [docs on github](https://github.com/jwvdiermen/grunt-include-source#the-includesource-task) provide a good overview of how the task is configured and works.

Additionally, [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21232889/how-to-include-scripts-automatically-in-a-yeoman-grunt-project) to this other question provides a little more info.