# Absolute Path Script Removed After Grunt Build.. Need to fix it

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

Whenever i am using grunt build, absolute path script is being removed automatically, how to fix it.

Example:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&libraries=places&language=en-US"></script>
```

This external file script has been removed from my index html

how can it be fixed???

Answer (score 0):

> Now that SSL is encouraged for everyone and doesn’t have performance
>   concerns, this technique is now an anti-pattern. If the asset you need
>   is available on SSL, then always use the https:// asset.
>
> Allowing the snippet to request over HTTP opens the door for attacks
>   like the recent Github Man-on-the-side attack. It’s always safe to
>   request HTTPS assets even if your site is on HTTP, however the reverse
>   is not true.

You should use this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&libraries=places&language=en-US"></script>
```

instead

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&libraries=places&language=en-US"></script>
```

**EDIT**
There is an another way in `grunt`. Please check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21232889/how-to-include-scripts-automatically-in-a-yeoman-grunt-project) URL

```
<!-- build:js({.tmp,dist,app}) /scripts/application.js -->
<!-- vendor, external -->
<script src="/maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&libraries=places&language=en-US"></script>


<!-- endbuild -->
```

Comment: but at the moment when I do 'grunt build' it removes this script tag from resulting index.html