# Can wiredep or anything else be used to insert <script> tags in HTML to include all .js files in given directories?

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman, wiredep, grunt-wiredep

Like you include bower sourced JS files in an HTML without specifying each script's URL, I want to include all JS files contained in a particular directory.
How to go about this? There could be more than one directories and the JS files may located at any depth in the specified directories.

```
<!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/about.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/contact.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

This sample code is from `index.html` of a yeoman generated project.
the `scripts` directory is in the `app` directory which is inturn specified as an argument to `build:js`.

As I understand `<!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->` tells wiredep to include all `js` files from the app directory and create a concatenated file `scripts/scripts.js`.

However, when I delete the `<script>` tags and run wiredep again, it does not recrate the `<script>` tags

```
<!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->

<!-- endbuild -->
```

Whereas if I delete the script tags for bower sourced JS files then wiredep recreates them.

Comment: You can to create a script at server to make a long string with the includes. And at server replace in the html. But I prefer to use require.js

Comment: I want to do this at build time, not run time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21363346/497828), I still doubt how will you handle dependencies ... I mean, scripts should be loaded via certain order to work. It's not like that you are going to leave that task to include all the files on its own and their order will be solved automatcailly.

You can also check out [this post](https://jhipster.github.io/tips/002_tip_include_js_grunt.html)