# Include scripts files recursively and wrap them with HTML Script tags

Tags: javascript

I have lots of files in sub folders and I have to include them in an html file , i.e  -

`<script src="folder2/file1.js"></script>`

for each file .

I'm looking for an easy way to run all the folders from a provided root folder and cause it to include to my `index.html` all the files .

i.e  - 
for the folder with -

```
folder1>
    file1.js
    file2.js
folder2>
    file1.js
```

it will be in the `index.html` -

```
<script src="folder1/file1.js"></script>
<script src="folder1/file2.js"></script>
<script src="folder2/file1.js"></script>
```

I don't want to concat them so please avoid from `grunt concat` suggestions .

Have you any smart idea ?

Comment: why do you want to achive this? usually this is not a good idea...how about minifying the scripts? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9287823/combine-and-minify-multiple-css-js-files

Comment: I'm working on dev environment and it's hard to debug a contacted single file with thousands of lines .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use [grunt-include-source](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-include-source)

That way, you avoid to use concat and get the expected result.

I'm not very familiar with it so I'd refer you to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21363346/5995433)