# grunt-include-source doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I try to make a simple using of - [grunt-include-source](https://github.com/jwvdiermen/grunt-include-source) but I don't success -

My Gruntfile is -

```
module.exports = function (grunt) { 
    grunt.initConfig({
      includeSource: {
        options: {
          basePath: 'app/file1.js'
        },
        myTarget: {
          files: {
            'dist/index.html': 'app/index.html'
          }
        }
      }
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-include-source');
    grunt.registerTask('serve', function (target) {
        grunt.task.run('includeSource');
    });
}
```

The index.html is -

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- include: "type": "js", "files": "scripts/*.js" -->
</body>
</html>
```

My folder hierarchy is  -

```
Gruntfile.js
app >
    file1.js
    index.html
dist >
    index.html
```

I run `grunt serve` and get in the `dist>index.html` folder the output -

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Without the expected -  `<script src="scripts/file1.js"></script>`

I kept to follow as in the [documentation](https://github.com/jwvdiermen/grunt-include-source) and in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21232889/how-to-include-scripts-automatically-in-a-yeoman-grunt-project) ,

Why I don't get the expected output ?

Comment: Could you post your complete gruntfile

Comment: This is the whole file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems with your code, first in gruntfile you are specifying a wrong path, second on your html you are specifying a wrong source.

Let's go by parts, on your gruntfile you have this:

```
...
  includeSource: {
    options: {
      basePath: 'app/file1.js'
    },
...
```

The basepath option on the docs says:

> Type: String or Array[String] Default value: ''
>
> The base path to use when expanding files. Can be an array to support
>   expanding files from multiple paths.

What this allows us to do is including one or more paths as our base path for our scripts. So let's change our basePath to `basePath: 'app'`, our **Gruntfile.js** will look like this:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    includeSource: {
      options: {
        basePath: 'app'
      },
      myTarget: {
        files: {
          'dist/index.html': 'app/index.html'
        }
      }
    }
  });
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-include-source');
  grunt.registerTask('serve', function (target) {
    grunt.task.run('includeSource');
  });
};
```

Now if we run `grunt serve` it won't work, why? Well because on your index.html you have this:

```
<!-- include: "type": "js", "files": "scripts/*.js" -->
```

Which means, insert script tags for all the javascript files, inside the **scripts** folder, but we don't have any scripts folder, so that's why your `dist/index.html` is empty. Let's change our index.html to this:

```
<!-- include: "type": "js", "files": "*.js" -->
```

Run `grunt serve` et voilà your index.html has changed to:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="file1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now you just have to copy `file1.js` from `app/` to `dist/`

Comment: Still , is there an option to indicate a particular js file  ?

Comment: @URL87 you could change your index.html file to `<!-- include: "type": "js", "files": "file1.js" -->`